# Get archive post type name

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I want to make function, which gets me a post type slug (or object - doesn't matter) of post type displaying in Archive page, or even on archive pages of its taxonomies. Is it possible?

I have this conditional function to recognize a post type (archive / single), but I would like it to return the name, if it's not set:

```
function rb_oftype($type = false) {
global $post;

if ( !$type ){
    //get the type [post_type,tax]


}

if ( count($post) > 0 ){
    //if is of post type

    if ( $post->post_type === $type ) return true;

}
elseif ( is_archive() ) {
    //added also for post type archives

    return is_post_type_archive( $type );

}
elseif ( is_tax() ){
    //also for all custom post taxonomy archives

    $taxonomies = (array) get_object_taxonomies($type);

    $keys = array_keys( $taxonomies );
    for ($i=0;$i<$keys;$i++)  if ( is_tax( $taxonomies[$keys[$i]] ) ) 

return true;

    }

    return false;
}
```

Can anybody help me with that? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_queried_object`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/) to get information about the current page.

- if you're on a single post, it will return the post object
- if you're on a page, it will return the page object
- if you're on an archive page, it will return the post type object
- if you're on a category archive, it will return the category object
- if you're on an author archive, it will return the author object
- etc.

Comment: Thanks, it works pretty good now. I was also able to simplify and improve the function (and condition) a bit